# JSOUP Unable to parse html string to document if a node value contains like <test@test.com>

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

Try to covert the HTML String to document through JSoup and failing with invalid XML characters.

This error possibly can happen when user copy email address from outlook.

It looks like, JSoup possibly could fail if a text with special characters preceded with >.
Example, <test@>,<test!>.

```
<html>
<table>
<tr>
   <td>
        <test@test.com>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Any idea, can make this works?

Comment: Can you use a custom `jsoup` `whitelist` to allow such entries?

Comment: Actually I tried that and it stripped off the value between <>

Comment: can you share your code. what you tried?

Comment: My suggestion would be to preprocess the content with a regex that finds these wrapped email addresses and escapes them (or does whatever you want). jsoup is a HTML parser, and that... isn't.

Comment: It looks that's the only option has left. Need to escape the HTML ASCII character and process them back.